# Opencart default email order template

Tags: opencart

I'm trying to change the catalog/view/theme/default/template/mail/order.tpl file to allow all the text from my product option to display. Currently it appears to stop at about 40 characters. I know you can look on the website for the full text, but it would be easier if it just displayed the whole of the text inputted by the customer in the email. 
e.g.
- Instructions: My initials K.J embr..
when I actually want 
- Instructions: My initials K.J embroidered on front please. 
Is it possible to lengthen this field on the template?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the length of character in the following file folder

```
model/checkout/order
```

Find the following function:

```
public function addOrderHistory($order_id, $order_status_id, $comment = '', $notify = false, $override = false) {
```

Change:

> (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value)

to:

> (utf8_strlen($value) > 40 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 40) . '..' :
>   $value)

You can make any of the number on it.

Comment: I've tried this out and it worked beautifully, thanks very much :-)